# Setting up git on windows to push to linux box

Tags: git, deployment

Currently my deployment method is just a standard SFTP upload to my VPS but from what I can see is that I could save alot of time by just pushing any changes to my server using git?

Git is completely new to me and Im stuggling to find any helpful information online to assist me as I develop on Win7 can anyone give me a run down or point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Git homepage is located here:

- http://git-scm.com/

Windows client for git is located here:

- http://git-scm.com/download/win

There's and excellent book available and an onl-line tutorial for learning git:

- http://git-scm.com/book
- http://try.github.com/

Finally, your server (VPS) will also need to have git installed, if you want to support remote repositories. Instructions are all in the book:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server